# Add a URL in faces message JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2

Requirement is to display a faces message to user which should include a clickable link.
The faces message is added in the backing bean.

I am currently displaying the message and in the next line displaying the link.

Is there a way to combine the link in the faces message.

```
    <h:inputHidden id="error"/>
 <h:message styleClass="error" for="error" />

<h:link value="Go to page"  outcome="login.xhtml"/>
```

Comment: Will the message contain <h:link value="Go to page"  outcome="login.xhtml"/> along with the text.
If we add the following code in faces-config.xml does it work.    <render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>javax.faces.Messages</component-family>
        <renderer-type>javax.faces.Messages</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.example.EscapableMessagesRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>

Comment: Only if you use normal HTML, not JSF components.